# Detect If The App Is Still Live On Google Play Store Programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, package, android-toast

Is There a way to check if the app is still live on Google play , if not show toast or an activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your button click execute this task (and change app id with your, to test your case)

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        boolean b = isAppLiveOnPlayStore("com.yourapp.id");
                        return b;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

                        if(aBoolean){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App is Live", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App is not Live", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }.execute();

public  boolean isAppLiveOnPlayStore(String appid) {

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appid))
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.connect();
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            conn.disconnect();
            return status==200;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("isAppLiveOnPlayStore", e.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I did this, but when i click on the button it shows "unfortunately has stopped"

Comment: did you added the permission  in manifiest ? if not please add:   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: _**Thank You**_ it's working Perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an app exists on play store, Using any network libraries like Retrofit,Volley, etc. Make a GET request using the below URL

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="application.packagename"
```

Use this URL and append the it with the package name of the application you want to check.

On the response of the request check the status code, if it's 200 the package exists, else if it's 404 it won't exist.

Comment: I mean , what code should i write on Button click, to check if the app is still live ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.